# Tab control and pre existing datagridview

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid on a wpf form. What I need is to have this datagrid reside on a tab control. Is it possible to juggle the xaml to achieve this or do I have to remove the datagrid and then add the tab control and then redo the datagrid within the tab control? I tried encapsulating the datagrid xaml between  tags but gave it no dimensions. That didn't get the required result.

Here is the datagrid xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="_dgvInventory"
                                         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                         VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                         IsReadOnly="True"
                                         SelectionMode="Single"
                                         SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                         RowHeaderWidth="30"
                                         SelectionChanged="DGVInventory_SelectionChanged"
                                         LoadingRow="DataGridLoadingRow"
                                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"
                                                              Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag ID"
                                                              Binding="{Binding TagId}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                                                              Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Number"
                                                              Binding="{Binding PartNumber}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial Number"
                                                              Binding="{Binding SerialNumber}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location"
                                                              Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Room"
                                                              Binding="{Binding Room}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inventory"
                                                              Binding="{Binding Inventory}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment"
                                                              Binding="{Binding OwnedComment}"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Search"
                                                     Click="SearchParts_Click" />
                                        <MenuItem Header="Masked Search" Click="MaskedSearchMenuItem_Click"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                             Value="Inv:found">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                          Value="GreenYellow"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                             Value="Inv:unfound">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                          Value="Salmon"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                             Value="unknown">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                          Value="Yellow"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                             Value="stray">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                          Value="LightBlue"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            </DataGrid>
```

It exists on a wpf window tab control. THe tab control has on it a few other datagrids and slider bars and such. What I need to do is place just this one particular datagrid on a tabcontrol which will itself be in the main tab control. I hope my question is clearer. I was wondering if in the xaml i could do something simple and create the mini tabcontrol and 'slide' it behind the datagrid (which will then be a child of the mini tab control). I apologize if my terminology is not the accepted norm. New at this.

Comment: Please don't call a WPF `Window` a "form". That's an insult to my beliefs and values.

Comment: Post your XAML... and also please clarify. Your question is really confusing and ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your after...

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <TabControl>
                    <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                        <Grid>
                            <DataGrid x:Name="_dgvInventory"
                                     VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                     VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                     IsReadOnly="True"
                                     SelectionMode="Single"
                                     SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                     RowHeaderWidth="30"
                                     SelectionChanged="DGVInventory_SelectionChanged"
                                     LoadingRow="DataGridLoadingRow"
                                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status"
                                                          Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag ID"
                                                          Binding="{Binding TagId}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                                                          Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Part Number"
                                                          Binding="{Binding PartNumber}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serial Number"
                                                          Binding="{Binding SerialNumber}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location"
                                                          Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Room"
                                                          Binding="{Binding Room}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Inventory"
                                                          Binding="{Binding Inventory}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment"
                                                          Binding="{Binding OwnedComment}"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Search"
                                                 Click="SearchParts_Click" />
                                        <MenuItem Header="Masked Search" Click="MaskedSearchMenuItem_Click"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                         Value="Inv:found">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                      Value="GreenYellow"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                         Value="Inv:unfound">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                      Value="Salmon"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                         Value="unknown">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                      Value="Yellow"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                         Value="stray">
                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                      Value="LightBlue"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

I noticed that when I dragged the child TabControl into the parent it appeared with no Items at all. And then you need a grid in each item.

Comment: Georgianbrit, thank you so much. The sample code was very helpful!